# Regex to extract second word from URL

Tags: regex

I want to extract a second word from my url.

Examples:

```
/search/acid/all    -   extract acid
/filter/ion/all/sss -  extract ion
```

I tried to some of the ways

```js
/.*/(.*?)/
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

- The forward slashes `/` have to be escaped like this `\/`
- The `(.*?)` will match the least amount of any character, **including zero characters**. In this case it will always match with an empty string.
- The `.*` will take as many characters as it can, including forward slashes

A simple solution will be:

```
/.+?\/(.*?)\//
```

**Update**:

Since you are using JavaScript, try the following code:

```
var url = "/search/acid/all";
var regex = /.+?\/(.*?)\//g;
var match = regex.exec(url);
console.log(match[1]);
```

The variable `match` is a list. The first element of that list is a full match (everything that was matched), you can just ignore that, since you are interested in the specific group we wanted to match (the thing we put in parenthesis in the regex).

You can see the working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qpafnjds/)

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply but this is extracting first and second word.

Comment: @divein What programming language are you using?

Comment: @divein I updated the code to show you how to get the second element using javascript as well as a small explanation of the code.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do the trick:

```
(?:[^\/]*.)\/([^\/]*)\/
```

[Proof](https://regex101.com/r/0NpWcy/2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Above regex working for php but not for javascript. Also my query is /search/acid/all . I edited the typo in my original post.

Comment: When language flavour put to Javascript, it still seems to work. https://regex101.com/r/sDd2Wh/1

Comment: ok, It gives me a two match 1). /search/acid/  2).acid. I just want 'acid' as a match.

Comment: It is group 1 that you should use :) Not the full match.

Comment: @divein I'm glad :D Make sure to upvote and/or mark as answer if this helped you! :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had difficulties with the above answers for URL without an ending forward slash:

```
/search/acid/all/        /* works */
/search/acid             /* doesn't work */
```

To extract the second word from both urls, what worked for me is

```
var url = "/search/acid";
var regex = /(?:[^\/]*.)\/([^\/]*)/g;
var match = regex.exec(url);
console.log(match[1]);
```